# El metodo funciona pero por alguna razon no setea bien todos lo datos

Tags: java

Mi método funciona correctamente me da de alta a una persona y si el departamento es nuevo me lo crea pero hay datos que no guarda por la dirección del departamento, el nombre del departamento. Ademas el numero del departamento me crea uno menos si le doy el departamento 1 me crea el 0 y si e doy el 2 el 1. Os dejo el Main y los metodos.

```
     case 1:
                        Persona p = new Persona();
                        int numDepartamento;
                        System.out.println("introduzca numero de departamento: ");
                        numDepartamento = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
                        if (base_datos.existeDepartamento(numDepartamento) == true) {
                            System.out.println("introduzca nombre de la persona: ");
                            p.setNombre(entrada.nextLine());
                            System.out.println("introduzca la identificacion de la persona: ");
                            p.setIdentificador(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));

                            if (base_datos.altaPersona(p)) {
                                System.out.println("Contacto dado de alta correctamente...");
                            } else {

                                System.out.println("Error al dar de alta un contacto...");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Departamento d = new Departamento();
                            System.out.println("introduzca nombre de la persona: ");
                            p.setNombre(entrada.nextLine());
                            System.out.println("introduzca la identificacion de la persona: ");
                            p.setIdentificador(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));
                            System.out.println("introduzca nombre del nuevo departamento: ");
                            d.setNombre(entrada.nextLine());
                            System.out.println("introduzca la direccion del nuevo departamento: ");
                            d.setDireccion(entrada.nextLine());
                            if (base_datos.altaPersona(p)) {
                                System.out.println("Contacto dado de alta correctamente...");
                            } else {

                                System.out.println("Error al dar de alta un contacto...");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("\nPresiona Intro para continuar....");
                        entrada.nextLine();
                        break;
```

Eso era el main esto son los metodos el importante es el 2º el primero es solo para que veais de donde sale lo que trae inlcuido.

```
 public boolean existeDepartamento(int num) {
        boolean existe = false;
        try {
            Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet res;
            res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT count(numDepto) total FROM departamento WHERE numDepto ='" + num + "'");

            if (res.next()) {
                existe = res.getInt("total") > 0 ? true : false;

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return existe;
    }

    public boolean altaPersona(Persona p) {
        boolean flag = false;
        boolean existe = false;
        int numDepartamento = p.getNumDepartamento();
        try {
            if (existeDepartamento(numDepartamento) == true) {
                Statement orden1 = conn.createStatement();
                orden1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona(identificador,nombrePersona,numDepartamento)  VALUES('"
                        + p.getIdentificador() + "','" + p.getNombre() + "','" + p.getNumDepartamento() + "')");
                flag = true;

            } else {
                Departamento d = new Departamento();
                Statement orden2 = conn.createStatement();
                orden2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO departamento(Nombre, direccion, numDepto)  VALUES('"
                        + d.getNombre() + "','" + d.getDireccion() + "','" + numDepartamento + "')");
                orden2.close();
                Statement orden3 = conn.createStatement();
                orden3.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona(identificador,nombrePersona,numDepartamento)  VALUES('"
                        + p.getIdentificador() + "','" + p.getNombre() + "','" + p.getNumDepartamento() + "')");
                orden3.close();
                flag = true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Una pregunta el nº de departamento que meto en el main me lo guarda para el 2º método o no? gracias

Comment: altapersona esta mal. cuando haces Departamento d = new Departamento(); creaste un nuevo objeto vacio. y por lo tanto, no va a guardar ningun dato. No deberias ya saber que departamento es? o por lo menos tu clase departamento deberia tener un metodo en el cual le pases el numero de departamento, y este llene el resto de los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a enumerar lo que veo que hay error:

1. Primero en el método altaPersona extraes de la persona recibida el numero de departamento`int numDepartamento = p.getNumDepartamento();` pero sin embargo, en el main, no se ve en en ningún lado que le setees a esa persona (que has creado) ese valor. Te falta un set antes de llamar al método`p.setNumDepartamento(numDepartamento)`
2. Si el departamento no existe, creas uno nuevo y lo insertas. Pero a ese departamento no le has fijado los valores de nombre y dirección.

   ```
   } else {
           Departamento d = new Departamento();
           Statement orden2 = conn.createStatement();
           orden2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO departamento(Nombre, direccion, numDepto)  VALUES('"
                   + d.getNombre() + "','" + d.getDireccion() + "','" + numDepartamento + "')");
           orden2.close();
   ....
   ```

Se que estas seteando esos valores en el main, pero ese objeto departamento que le seteas los valores, no lo estas pasando a altaPersona.

---

Solución. El Main esta bien excepto en un punto.

En la segunda parte (cuando no existe el departamento) cuando llames al método, añádele el departamento

```
....
if (base_datos.altaPersona(p,d)) {
....
```

Estas son las modificaciones para el método altaPersona()

```
public boolean altaPersona(Persona p) {
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean existe = false;
    int numDepartamento = p.getNumDepartamento();
    try {           
            Statement orden1 = conn.createStatement();
            orden1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona(identificador,nombrePersona,numDepartamento)  VALUES('"
                    + p.getIdentificador() + "','" + p.getNombre() + "','" + p.getNumDepartamento() + "')");
            flag = true;


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return flag;
}

//Sobrecargamos el método altaPersona. Aquí se llama cuando el departamento no existe
public boolean altaPersona(Persona p, Departamento d) {
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean existe = false;
    int numDepartamento = p.getNumDepartamento();
    try {          

            Statement orden2 = conn.createStatement();
            orden2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO departamento(Nombre, direccion, numDepto)  VALUES('"
                    + d.getNombre() + "','" + d.getDireccion() + "','" + numDepartamento + "')");
            orden2.close();
            Statement orden3 = conn.createStatement();
            orden3.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona(identificador,nombrePersona,numDepartamento)  VALUES('"
                    + p.getIdentificador() + "','" + p.getNombre() + "','" + p.getNumDepartamento() + "')");
            orden3.close();
            flag = true;            
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

---

Consejo de codigo limpio `if (base_datos.existeDepartamento(numDepartamento) == true)` si el metodo devuelve un booleano, no necesitas compararlo con true o false

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio de mucho ya funciono efectivamente el problema era el crear el departamento dentro del metodo en vez de darlo como parametro.